# Creating a foreign key with SQLAlchemy

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've looked online for answers and followed the SQLAlchemy Documentation but I don't understand it.

I have the following code (I'm using Flask with SQLAlchemy):

```
class accounts(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'accounts'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)


class questions(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'questions'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    accountID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('accounts.id'))
    question = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
```

I want the `accountID` in the questions table to be linked with the `id` column in the accounts table. Though I don't know how and what I've read, I don't understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to have the relationship set up. I've changed a few definitions in your setup which usually help me disambiguate table names vs models (class names) vs field names. The following code should work for you. Don't forget to import: `from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship`.

```
class Account(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'accounts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    questions = relationship("Question", backref="accounts")

class Question(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'questions'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    account_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('accounts.id'))
    body = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
```

The setup above will also allow you to fetch all the questions associated with an account (using `Account.questions`).

More in [SQL Alchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many) on this topic.